# How to spacing between images without any space with their container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div with images inside it, and there is space between them. For example, I want the space between them is 2px, I can use `margin:1px;` so it will become 2px when one's left-margin meet other's right-margin, same for top and bottom. But there is also space between image and div's border, so the div will become like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|  +---------------+    +---------------+  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |      IMG1     |    |      IMG2     |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  +---------------+    +---------------+  |
|           DIV                            |
|                                          |
|  +---------------+    +---------------+  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |      IMG3     |    |      IMG4     |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  |               |    |               |  |
|  +---------------+    +---------------+  |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------+
```

When what I'm actually trying to do, is this:

```
+---------------+---+---------------+
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
|      IMG1     |   |      IMG2     |
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
+---------------+   +---------------+
|        DIV                        |
|                                   |
+---------------+   +---------------+
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
|      IMG3     |   |      IMG4     |
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
|               |   |               |
+---------------+---+---------------+
```

How to do this, without set style for every single image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If adding classes or  IDs is not an option and you do not want to style the images individually. Then you could try using [`img:nth-child(n)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) or [`img:nth-of-type(n)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).

First assign a right margin to every odd image:

```
img:nth-of-type(odd){
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Then a left margin to every even:

```
img:nth-of-type(even){
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

And finally a top margin to every image but the first two:

```
img:nth-of-type(n+3){
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

You could also leave out one of the left or right margins and increase the one you leave in... thereby reducing the size of your styles a little.

Here an example: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x7sR/1/)**. In this example the container div has a set width of two images plus margins, and the images are floating left within.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/G6GL6/)

You can set your bottom margins and align your left column images with the float property in your CSS:

```
img {
    margin-bottom: /*your margin*/;
    float: left;
}
```

And then move the right column images to the right of the div container:

```
nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give all images a same class & define padding for it

try this

```
<div>
  <img src="1.jpg" class="myimage"/>
  <img src="2.jpg" class="myimage"/>
  <img src="3.jpg" class="myimage"/>
  <img src="4.jpg" class="myimage"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.myimage {
  display:block;
  padding:2px 2px 0 0;
}
```